# Apache Isis Custom menu icon

Tags: isis

I want to change my default Menu Icon using FoneAwesome Icon, e.g Day Off Calendar use `calendar` icon. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solve this by very easy solutions which already exist on `Apache Isis`, just use `cssClassFa` on `ActionLayout` annotation as bellow.

> @ActionLayout(bookmarking = BookmarkPolicy.AS_ROOT, cssClassFa = "calendar")

Comment: http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugfun/ugfun.html#_ugfun_ui-hints_action-icons-and-css  and   http://isis.apache.org/guides/rgant/rgant.html#_rgant-ActionLayout_cssClassFa